# How to parse CSON to Ruby object?

Tags: ruby, coffeescript

I am trying to read CSON (CoffeeScript Object Notation) into Ruby.

I am looking for something similar to `data = JSON.parse(file)` that one would use for JSON files.

```
file = File.read(filename)
data = CSON.parse(file)        # does not exist - would like to have
```

I looked into invoking CoffeeScript and JavaScript from Ruby, but it feels overly complicated and like reinventing the wheel. Also, code in the data file should not be executed.

How can I read CSON into Ruby objects in a simple way?

Comment: Well, if you don't find an existing parser, you could always create one, so that the next poor soul can have it quickly.

Comment: The notation for objects looks very much like yaml, so maybe you could use yaml parser here.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with. It is sufficient for the data I am processing. The main work is done with the YAML parser Psych (https://github.com/ruby/psych). Arrays, hashes, and some of the multi-line text require a special treatment.

```
module CSON

  def load_file(fname)
    load_string File.read fname
  end

  def remove_indent(data)
    out = ""
    data.each_line do |line|
      out += line.sub /^\s\s/,""
    end
    out
  end

  def parse_array(data)
    data.gsub! /\n/, ","
    data.gsub! /([\[\{]),/, '\1'
    data.gsub! /,([\]\}])/, '\1'
    YAML.load data
  end

  def load_string(data)
    hashed = {}

    data.gsub! /^(\w+):\s+(\[.*?\])/mu do # find arrays
      key   =             Regexp.last_match[1]
      value = parse_array Regexp.last_match[2]
      hashed[key] = value
      ""
    end

    data.gsub! /(\w+):\s+\'\'\'\s*\n(.*?)\'\'\'/mu do # find heredocs
      hashed[Regexp.last_match[1]] = remove_indent Regexp.last_match[2]
      ""
    end
    hashed.merge YAML.load data
  end
end
```

This solution is likely to fail when applied to more complicated .cson files. I would be happy to see if someone has a more elegant answer!